# i am starting my JHIPSTER maven server but am getting error

Tags: jhipster

2020-08-23 18:22:07.375 ERROR 19542 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : Hikari - Exception during pool initialization.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$44799bee.getConnection()
at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:90)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:662)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:346)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:114)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed1b2885.CGLIB$servletEndpointRegistrar$0()
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed1b2885$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8f25236.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ed1b2885.servletEndpointRegistrar()
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:252)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:226)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory$Initializer.onStartup(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:592)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:203)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:279)
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at com.om.app.DemoApp.main(DemoApp.java:65)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:152)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:955)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:825)
... 129 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
... 132 common frames omitted

2020-08-23 18:22:07.380 ERROR 19542 --- [  restartedMain] i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:455)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke()
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
at

Comment: "_Liquibase could not start correctly, your database is NOT ready_" We can't really tell you anymore that what the message already says - your DB is not up and running and ready to process requests.

Comment: That looks like it can't reach its database. Can you check the MySQL configuration and the connection? Can you make a connection to the database using the same connection settings and credentials from the machine too to rule out firewall etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Your app could not connect to your database, you must start a MySQL Docker container with `docker-compose -f src/main/docker/mysql.yml up -d`

See official doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#mysql-mariadb-postgresql-oracle-mongodb-couchbase-neo4j-or-cassandra